# Prove the sequence $(x_n = \sin(\frac{n\pi}{100}))$ diverges.

Tags: real-analysis

I wanted to prove this by using subsequences that they converge to different values but doesn't seem to work out ?Is there any hint I could get to prove this?

Comment: What happens for the subsequence $n = 100k$? Can you find another subsequence that has another constant value?

Answer (score 4):

Since the subsequence $x_{50(2n+1)} = \sin((2n+1)\pi/2) = (-1)^{n}$ is divergent, $x_n$ is divergent.